# NodeJS: npx webpack command fails due to write EOF error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, eof

Okay, I'm not a programmer first of all, so I have 0 idea what is happening. Please go easy on me..

The project I'm trying to compile is a web browser extension (or webpack idk). There is a file called Installer.bat with the "npm i" command and a file called compiler.bat with the "npx webpack" command.

Now, there is no issue within the project, because it worked on the same machine  with different windows 7 with no problems. On this ystem (32-bit windows 7 by the way) I keep getting the following error when running compiler.bat file :

```
Error: write EOF
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)
```

I know I should probably link the webpack.config.js code here, but it's pretty big and I'm thinking that this error is ocurring because of something entirely different anyway. I will say that during the installation of nodejs, the additional chocolatey packages failed because of problems with powershell/TLS 1.2 or whatever. I do have python 3.6 installed though. Not sure if that matters but yeah. And also, my friend who downloaded it on his machine has also stumbled across an error with the compiler.bat but it was a EPIPE error.

Any ideas? Do I need to install something else besides NodeJS? This project isn't mine and it always compiled with no problems in the past (on the same machine but a different windows 7 though). I tried to look for answers for weeks, but found nothing. Mostly people just had issues with their project CODE not the nodejs or modules. I'm almost losing hope and the author of the project doesn't want to communicate for whatever reason.

EDIT: Apparently didn't have java sdk 8 installed, fixed the issue.